# Is there a way to do the inverse of Sprintf result

Tags: string, go, printf

So, I've created a string variable using

```golang
name := "Batman"
age := 38
nameAndAge = fmt.Sprintf("%s %d", name, age)
```

In another function, I can access the variable `nameAndAge`. Now I want to get back both the variables that I used in `Sprintf`. One oblivious way that I can think about is to split it based on the separator and create the variable. I wanted to know if there's any function available for doing that?

Like,

```golang
var name string
var age int
// " " is the separator here
fmt.ReverseSprintf(nameAndAge, " ", name, age)
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To some extent its possible, there's [`fmt.Sscanf()`](https://play.golang.org/p/8qsOy-HL23G) for this. Quoting from package doc of [`fmt`: Scanning](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Scanning):

> Scanf, Fscanf, and Sscanf parse the arguments according to a format string, analogous to that of Printf.

See this example:

```
name := "Batman"
age := 38
output := fmt.Sprintf("%s %d", name, age)

fmt.Println(output)

var name2 string
var age2 int
if _, err := fmt.Sscanf(output, "%s %d", &name2, &age2); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error", err)
}
fmt.Println(name2, age2)
```

It outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1uod7HjDOli)):

```
Batman 38
Batman 38
```

I wrote "to some extent" because your example was quite simple. If your `name` would have contained spaces, the above example would've broke:

```
name := "Batman Robin"
// The rest is the same
```

Output would be:

```
Batman Robin 38
error expected integer
Batman 0
```

The reason for this is because in our format `string` we used space to separate inputs, and if the space itself is contained in the input, the reversing process can't tell the difference. Also the scanning functions treat newlines in the input as spaces, among other differences.